# Find limit of Interpolated function

Tags: interpolation

I have an interpolated function

```
f = Interpolation[data]
```

I would like to calculate limits such as

```
Limit[(f[1.5 + h] - f[1.5])/h, h -> 0]
```

I just get errors.

Comment: That's just the derivative you want; try `f'[1.5]`.

Comment: `Limit` is a purely algebraic tool.  You could try `NLimit` from the `NumericalCalculus` package. I concur with J.M., however, that your specific example would be best approached with `f'`.

Comment: I know it's the derivative. I want my students to find a derivative with a limit.

Comment: In general, interpolated functions seem fussy compared to user defined functions.

Comment: Plus, even if Limit is an algebraic tool, doesn't mathematica have a polynomial for the interpolant? I know it can do limits of polynomials.

Comment: Uhmm... `NLimit`?

Comment: NLimit gives errors too. It seems like f is not treated like a normal function. For example, I don't get a function g if I try g = D[f[x],x]. I don't get an h with h=2*f[x]

Comment: While I agree it might be a reasonable thing to do, at this time `Limit` is not going inside the `InterpolatingFunction` to extract a local interpolant polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<< NumericalCalculus`
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, x  x}, {x, 1, 5}]];
NLimit[(f[3 + h] - f[3])/h, h -> 0]
(*
 6
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not working for me. I am not sure how to copy and paste my code into a comment to show you. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: I still get errors, but I am at least getting an answer along with the errors now. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why I needed the <<NumericalCalculus`? Isn't NLimit already defined without any special packages? That line is what seems to make the difference

Comment: @user, because `NLimit[]` is not built-in, and it is in the ``NumericalCalculus` `` package which needs to be explicitly loaded...